# Кто всетречался с проблемой заполнения полей в Selenium-webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara

Проблема заключается в том что во фрейме я заполняю поле значением типа 1111 1111 1111 2222 , а выдает  1121 1121 1111 2211 к примеру

сам метод find('#card_number').set("1111111111112222")
mac osx sierra
capybara
selenum webdriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

судя по формату, заполняете номер банковской карты. Скорей всего есть JS, который разбивает цифры по 4. Видимо, когда вы заполняете всё одни запросом, JS сходим с ума. Если поля ввода для каждой группы имеют свои локаторы, то попробуйте отправлять по 4 цифры в каждое поле. Или заполнять, имитируя нажатия клавиш клавиатуры: `find().sendkeys()`

Comment: спасибо огромное! именно этот метод мне и помог

Comment: не могли бы тогда отметить мой ответ, как правильный?

Comment: "не могли бы тогда отметить мой ответ, как правильный? " - готово